# Swing: Malayalam string not rendering correctly in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jframe

I am trying to show a malayalam string in a Jframe.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("InputDialog");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,  word );
```

I am writing the same String into a property xml file.

```
PropertyManager.setProperty("Result.xml", "result", word);
```

String is shown correctly inside the xml file:
[image: Malayalam in xml file.]
But its show wrong in the JFrame:
[image: Malayalam in Jframe]
How can I make malayalam string render correctly in Swing?

SSCCE: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=CPYEhYkf

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MalayalamSSCCE {

    public static final String malluString = "എണ്‍പത്തേഴുലക്ഷത്തി അറുപത്തയ്യായിരത്തി നാന്നൂറ്റിമുപ്പത്തിരണ്ടു";
//Download font from http://www.findthatfonts.com/search-31416-hTTF/fonts-download-search-engine-thooliuc.ttf.htm
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FontFormatException,
            IOException {
        Frame frame = new Frame("Message frame.");

        BufferedInputStream fontInStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                new FileInputStream("ThooliUc.TTF"));
        Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontInStream);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(malluString);
            label.setFont(font.deriveFont(14f));    
        JOtionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, label);
    }
}
```

Complete Source: https://bitbucket.org/vishnuholmes/wordizer-malayalam/src/fe63167a22413644cbae40ad506cc6112eb9f322/src?at=default

Comment: Have you tried to change the font?

Comment: @GuillaumePoussel Yes, I have tried Thoolika Unicode font and many other. No Luck.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Posted the link to the full sourcecode

Comment: @AndrewThompson Posted SSCCE. Thanks for the tip. :)

Comment: Same string in ASCII: `"\u0d0e\u0d23\u0d4d\u200d\u0d2a\u0d24\u0d4d\u0d24\u0d47\u0d34\u0d41\u0d32\u0d15\u0d4d\u0d37\u0d24\u0d4d\u0d24\u0d3f \u0d05\u0d31\u0d41\u0d2a\u0d24\u0d4d\u0d24\u0d2f\u0d4d\u0d2f\u0d3e\u0d2f\u0d3f\u0d30\u0d24\u0d4d\u0d24\u0d3f \u0d28\u0d3e\u0d28\u0d4d\u0d28\u0d42\u0d31\u0d4d\u0d31\u0d3f\u0d2e\u0d41\u0d2a\u0d4d\u0d2a\u0d24\u0d4d\u0d24\u0d3f\u0d30\u0d23\u0d4d\u0d1f\u0d41"`

Comment: Regarding the SSCCE:  Setting the font of a parent Frame does not set the font of a JOptionPane.  Try:  `JLabel label = new JLabel(malluString); label.setFont(font.deriveFont(14f)); JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, label);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick seems to be to create a `JLabel` and set the font on the label before handing it to the `JOptionPane`.  There might also be some clever UI default that covers it.  See [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) to investigate that further.

[image]

I could not find a version of that `Font` to which I could hot link (for an SSCCE), but try this variant.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MalayalamSSCCE {

    public static final String malluString = "\u0d0e\u0d23\u0d4d\u200d\u0d2a\u0d24\u0d4d\u0d24\u0d47\u0d34\u0d41\u0d32\u0d15??\u0d4d\u0d37\u0d24\u0d4d\u0d24\u0d3f \u0d05\u0d31\u0d41\u0d2a\u0d24\u0d4d\u0d24\u0d2f\u0d4d\u0d2f\u0d3e\u0d2f\u0d3f\u0d30\u0d24\u0d4d\u0d24\u0d3f \u0d28\u0d3e\u0d28\u0d4d\u0d28\u0d42\u0d31\u0d4d\u0d31\u0d3f\u0d2e\u0d41\u0d2a\u0d4d\u0d2a\u0d24\u0d4d\u0d24\u0d3f\u0d30\u0d23\u0d4d\u0d1f\u0d41";

    public static Font getFirstFontThatCanDisplay(String text) {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge =
                GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        String[] fontNameArray = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
        for (String name : fontNameArray) {
            Font f = new Font(name, Font.PLAIN, 20);
            if (f.canDisplayUpTo(text)<0) return f;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Font f = getFirstFontThatCanDisplay(malluString);
        System.out.println(f);

        JLabel l = new JLabel(malluString);
        l.setFont(f);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, l);
    }
}
```

It ends up using:

```
java.awt.Font[family=Arial Unicode MS,name=Arial Unicode MS,style=plain,size=20]
```